# How to use phonegap to listen for screen touch-start and touch-end

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Is there any way to (for example) get the location where the user touches the android screen and where the user ends touching it, or some function like onUserScreenTouch(x,y), onUserScreenDragged(x,y) ... and so on? For example I want to drag a rectangle that's inside an html5 canvas from its starting position to wherever the user drags it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, we could use ontouchstart/end